# How to extract specific information from multiple files and make a table in linux?

Tags: linux, grep, text-files, tabular, text-extraction

I have multiple text files with information. Here I'm showing for two text files which are like below:

Sample1.txt

```
Status  /documents/Sample1.sorted.bam
Assigned        50945040
Unassigned_Unmapped     947866
Unassigned_MappingQuality       0
Unassigned_Chimera      0
Unassigned_FragmentLength       0
Unassigned_Duplicate    0
Unassigned_MultiMapping 49013681
Unassigned_Secondary    0
Unassigned_Nonjunction  0
Unassigned_NoFeatures   21189312
Unassigned_Overlapping_Length   0
Unassigned_Ambiguity    4430011
```

Sample2.txt

```
Status  /documents/Sample2.sorted.bam
Assigned        36335614
Unassigned_Unmapped     870456
Unassigned_MappingQuality       0
Unassigned_Chimera      0
Unassigned_FragmentLength       0
Unassigned_Duplicate    0
Unassigned_MultiMapping 68688141
Unassigned_Secondary    0
Unassigned_Nonjunction  0
Unassigned_NoFeatures   23746485
Unassigned_Overlapping_Length   0
Unassigned_Ambiguity    3734593
```

For single text file I'm using grep:

```
grep "Assigned\|Unmapped\|MultiMapping\|NoFeatures\|Ambiguity" Sample1.txt > output.txt
```

But I want the output to be like below were I can use a small script on all text file and make table:

```
                        Sample1       Sample2
Assigned                50945040      36335614
Unassigned_Unmapped     947866        870456
Unassigned_MultiMapping 49013681      68688141
Unassigned_NoFeatures   21189312      23746485
Unassigned_Ambiguity    4430011       3734593
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2 != 0 {
    printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? $1 : "Name"), OFS
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        gsub(/^.*\/|\..*$/,"",$i)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ paste Sample1.txt Sample2.txt | awk -f tst.awk | column -t
Name                     Sample1   Sample2
Assigned                 50945040  36335614
Unassigned_Unmapped      947866    870456
Unassigned_MultiMapping  49013681  68688141
Unassigned_NoFeatures    21189312  23746485
Unassigned_Ambiguity     4430011   3734593
```

To get output that Excel can understand rather than the output shown in the question do this:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="," }
$2 != 0 {
    printf "%s%s", (NR>1 ? $1 : "Name"), OFS
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) {
        gsub(/^.*\/|\..*$/,"",$i)
        printf "%s%s", $i, (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ paste Sample1.txt Sample2.txt | awk -f tst.awk > output.csv
```

and then double-click on output.csv to open it with Excel.

Comment: this worked but, all the columns were present in a single column. I want them to be in different columns (First column: Name, Second column: Sample1, third column: Sample2, fourth column: Sample3....so on...And could you please explain a little about what are NF, NR, OFS, ORS in the code. Thank you

Comment: As you can see in my answer, the output **is** multiple columns as you wanted so I don't understand what `all the columns were present in a single column` means. Maybe your input file contains DOS line-endings (control-Ms) which would cause all columns to appear to overwrite each other? Run `cat -v` on an input file to see it and If present then run `dos2unix` on the files first to remove them or add `{sub(/\r/,"")}` as the first line of the awk script. Those are the basic awk built-in variables so just look them up in the man page.

Comment: There are no DOS line-endings in the files. I just gave this "paste *.txt.summary | awk -f tst.awk | column -t > output.txt" When I opened output.txt file I see all the data in only one column (which means the data is not separated into different columns)

Comment: You're going to have to try a little harder to explain the problem you're having. As you can see in my answer the output is clearly 3 columns. When you run `paste *.txt.summary | awk -f tst.awk | column -t` do you or do you not see the same output as shown in my answer being printed on your screen? When you say `When I opened output.txt file...` - what **exactly** do you mean by "opened"? Which tool are you using to "open" it? Does that tool require any specific character (or string) to be used to separate the columns so that it understands what a "column" is in your data?

Comment: Hi Ed, After getting the output.txt I opened that with Microsoft Excel. The whole data was seen in a single column. Then I separated them into different columns using "Text to columns" in Excel.

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. The problem has to do with your specified desired output in your question. My tool outputs what you asked for but what you asked for is not a format that Excel can understand. For excel to read a text file as separate columns, that input file has to be separated by specific characters, e.g. `,`, not by varying sequences of blank chars that provide tabular alignment like you asked for in your question and so I provided in my answer. Give me one sec and I'll add a version that outputs text that Excel can read as columns.

Comment: Done. See my updated answer. I just made the output comma-separated instead of a table.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. As I asked before could you please explain a little about the code. What are NF, NR, OFS, ORS and other symbols in the code.

Comment: You're welcome. As I replied before, they're builtin awk variables described in detail in the man page. Just take a look at that.